# All months not displayed in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Code:

```
var margin = {top: 30, right: 40, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%b").parse;
var formatTime = d3.time.format("%B");

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height,0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.month); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.shop2); });

var valueline2 = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.month); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.shop1); });

var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
    .attr("class", "tooltip")               
    .style("opacity", 0);

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.month = parseDate(d.month);
        d.shop1 = +d.shop1;
        d.shop2 = +d.shop2;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.month; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return (d.shop1, d.shop2); })]);


});

</script>
</body>
```

**Dataset: data.csv**

```
month,shop1,shop2
Jan,100,98
Feb,103,99
Mar,110,110
Apr,112,111
May,102,99
Jun,99,98
Jul,100,97
Aug,101,99
Sep,102,97
```

**Output:**
[image]

I'm new to javaScript and D3 and was wondering what could be wrong with my code. I'm getting 1900 instead of 'Jan' in the final plot but all the other months are displayed properly. Any help with this is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);
```

do this to give the format of the x axis tick

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).ticks(5)
.orient("bottom").tickFormat(d3.time.format("%b"));
```

Comment: OP already has `var formatTime = d3.time.format("%B");`, but he didn't use it.